# How to calculate a time-series vraiable in real time?

Tags: javascript, statistics

I have a simple code, that I used to compare historical variables and current data. Below is the short inroduction to variables, which I later compared.

```
  fv = exactMath.add(exactMath.mul(busdVolume,fv_busd), exactMath.div(exactMath.mul(fv_usdt,usdtVolume), busd_price))

  fvs[n] = fv
  if(n==0){
    ma[n] = fvs[n]
  }else if(n>0){
    ma[n]= (exactMath.mul(0.1,fv)) + (exactMath.mul(0.9,ma[n-1]))
```

I am having a hard time understanding, how can I calculate volatility(variance) for a time series? For example:

`var_fv[n] = (sum of (fvs[n] - average of sequance fvs[n])^2) / n-1 ;`

Is there any way to make it trail with n? I mean, if n is 200 it should calculate 200 values, and if n is 400, it should take values from 200 to 400 for calculation.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but I think you're saying you only want to use **n** values in your calculation. You could use [Array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get part of your original array.

Comment: How do you calculate the average?

Comment: I want to calculate variance of the time-series, but it should trail as data moves forward.